# Why should I use new Vector3? What is the difference?

Tags: c#

I am completely new to c#, and pretty new to programming in general, but I have been watching many tutorials and going through the steps on my own for about 2 weeks now.  I love watching the tutorials because it allows me to follow along which helps with understanding certain functions. However, sometimes something is presented that the narrarator seems to glide past, and Im left just memorizing doing something, but I want to know why.

With that said, here is my code to rotate an object.  It works just fine.

```
transform.Rotate(15 * Time.deltaTime, 30 * Time.deltaTime, 45 * 
Time.deltaTime);
```

I would like to first know why I couldnt do:

```
transform.Rotate(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime;
```

And second, I want to know why the tutorial suggested the below line, and why I should use that instead.

```
 transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime);
```

Please help me understand the concepts here!
Thanks for your time

Comment: SO isn't really a place to explain mathematical concepts like _matrices and vectors_

Comment: @MickyD Though the question indeed does not belong to SO, but the topic is  *operators and precedence*, not vectors and matrices.

Comment: @PepitoSh it's nothing to do with that either.

Comment: OP asked about language concepts.

Comment: @PepitoSh Last time I checked, c# didn't have Unity3D built into it.

Comment: Who was talking about Unity3D? The OP used examples to demonstrate what he does not understand about the language. He was not asking about how to rotate objects.

Answer (score 0):

In this code `transform.Rotate(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime;` the * operator is applied to the object what the Rotate method returns. It is too late for you to change the rotation parameters.

`Vector3` implements the * operator. It is more simple and readable to write code this way.

We are lucky, the Rotate method has more implementations and can accept either 3 double values or a single `Vector3` value. You can decide which implementation to use, according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The second example you provided wouldn't produce the output you expect.

```
transform.Rotate(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime;
```

The 'Rotate' function is what is actually applying the rotate. So this would result in a rotation using the vector defined as (15, 30, 45). You're then just multiplying the result by the delta time after it's already done rotating.

The first example is simply a more verbose version of the third example, so I'll just cover the third. The third function initializes the vector, multiplies it by Time.deltaTime, and then calls the transform.Rotate function on this result. This would result in the intended behavior.

Basically, keep track of your order of operations. Parenthesis (the function call) comes before any outer multiplication.

Comment: _"in a rotation to the vector defined as (15, 30, 45)"_ - it's not really rotation around a  _"vector"_, it's an expression of euler angles; usually an axis.   It's not a quaternion

Comment: You're right on this, should have been more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem good sir.  Nice answer just the same. +1  Wishing you well